# Convert a float to an int

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I have a price for a car, let's say 10000. I want to apply a 20% sale to this price.

I have a `struct` in which `auta->cena` is a `float`.

```
int year, i, n=0, pocet=1, sale;

scanf(" %d", &year);
scanf(" %d", &sale);

for(i=1; i<=pocet; i++){
    if(year == auta->rok){
        ++n;
        pocet++;

        auta->cena *= ((float)(100 - sale) / 100); //calculate price after 20% sale
        //temp = ((int)(temp * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0; //use this formula to round up final price, it doesnt work, I get 0.00


        printf("%.2f\n", auta->cena);
    }
        auta = auta->dalsi;
}
```

I am not good at converting—can anyone explain it to me, please? How should I go about it?

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct values until rounding?

Comment: yes, it works untill rounding

Comment: You might want to print the value of `temp` after `temp *= ((float)(100 - sale) / 100)`. It may not be what you expect...

Comment: I updated code but still, didnt change the logic, and I really get correct price after 20% sale.

Comment: ((int)(temp * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0 should be (int)((temp * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0) ... When casting int to float, it should be the first thing you do, and from float to int the last.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to print the value with `%.2f`, you don't have to do any rounding. But if  you want to round the value internally, the following will work. I'm printing it with `%.5f` to show that the value is really changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int discount;
  double price;

  printf("Enter a price: ");
  scanf(" %lf", &price);
  printf("Enter a percentage discount: ");
  scanf(" %d", &discount);

  price *= (100.0 - discount) / 100;  // calculate price after discount
  printf("after discount: %.5f\n", price);

  price = (int)(100 * price + 0.5) / 100.0;
  printf("rounded: %.5f\n", price);
}
```

I'm using `double` above to preserve enough precision to demonstrate that the calculation works with, for example, a price of 10000 and a discount of 20. If you do it with `float`, you lose enough precision that there's no point in rounding to the nearest cent. The internal value will be imprecise anyway.

Here is a variant of the same code using `float`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int discount;
  float price;

  printf("Enter a price: ");
  scanf(" %f", &price);
  printf("Enter a percentage discount: ");
  scanf(" %d", &discount);

  price *= (100.0 - discount) / 100;  // calculate price after discount
  printf("after discount: %.5f\n", price);

  price = (int)(100 * price + 0.5) / 100.0;
  printf("rounded up: %.5f\n", price);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my code or your code? I don't have any `float` variables.

Comment: I've added a version using `float`.